# Powershell ignores parameter passed via SessionStateProxy.SetVariable

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-sdk

I have the following Powershell script.

```
param([String]$stepx="Not Working")
echo $stepx
```

I then try using the following C# to pass a parameter to this script.

```
        using (Runspace space = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            space.Open();
            space.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("stepx", "This is a test");

            Pipeline pipeline = space.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript("test.ps1");

            var output = pipeline.Invoke(); 
        }
```

After the above code snippet is run, the value "not working" is in the output variable. It should be "This is a test". Why is that parameter ignored?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining `$stepx` as a *variable*, which is not the same as passing a value to your script's `$stepx` *parameter*.
The variable exists independently of the parameter, and since you're not passing an *argument* to your script, its parameter is bound to its default value.

Therefore, you need to pass an argument (parameter value) to your script's parameter:

Somewhat confusingly, **a script *file* is invoked via a `Command` instance**, to which you pass arguments (parameter values) via its `.Parameters` collection.

By contrast, **`.AddScript()`** is used to add a string as the *contents* of an *in-memory* script (stored in a string), i.e., **a *snippet of PowerShell source code***.

You can use *either* technique to invoke a script *file* with parameters, though if you want to use *strongly typed* arguments (whose values cannot be unambiguously inferred from their string representations), use the `Command`-based approach (the `.AddScript()` alternative is mentioned in comments):

```
  using (Runspace space = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
  {
    space.Open();

    Pipeline pipeline = space.CreatePipeline();

    // Create a Command instance that runs the script and
    // attach a parameter (value) to it.
    // Note that since "test.ps1" is referenced without a path, it must
    // be located in a dir. listed in $env:PATH
    var cmd = new Command("test.ps1");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("stepx", "This is a test");

    // Add the command to the pipeline.
    pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);

    // Note: Alternatively, you could have constructed the script-file invocation
    // as a string containing a piece of PowerShell code as follows:
    //   pipeline.Commands.AddScript("test.ps1 -stepx 'This is a test'");

    var output = pipeline.Invoke(); // output[0] == "This is a test"
  }
```