# C# Application console - powershell script as admin to install uwp msix packages

Tags: c#, powershell, console-application

I am trying to create an application console to install an UWP package in sideload.
Using the command directly in powershell works fine.
The .exe of the application run by administrator:

```xml
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

There are 2 commands the program runs.

1. Installation of the certificate in TrustedPeople store like below

```cs
string certCommand0 = "Import-Certificate -FilePath THEFILEPATH -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\\LocalMachine\\TrustedPeople' -Verbose";
string certCommand1 = certCommand0.Replace("THEFILEPATH", certificate);
```

-- THIS PART OF THE CODE WORKS FINE WITH THE ATTRIBUTE AS ADMINISTRATOR --

2. Installation of the package somehow does not work. Here is the code below:

```cs
    public static string Command(string script/*, string filePath*/)
    {
      string errorMsg = string.Empty;

      ps.AddScript(script);
      ps.AddArgument("Start-Process -FilePath \"powershell\" -Verb RunAs");

      ps.AddCommand("Out-string");

      PSDataCollection<PSObject> outPutCollection = new();
      ps.Streams.Error.DataAdded += (object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e) =>
      {
         errorMsg = ((PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>)sender)[e.Index].ToString();
      };

      IAsyncResult result = ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outPutCollection);

      ps.EndInvoke(result);

      StringBuilder sb = new();

      foreach (var outputItem in outPutCollection)
      {
         sb.AppendLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString());
      }

      ps.Commands.Clear();

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg))
          return errorMsg;

      return sb.ToString().Trim();
    }
```

When trying to install the package, the following error occured:
"The 'Add-AppxPackage' command was found in the module 'Appx', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Appx'"

I made some researches and find one potential solution which was to had the following line :

```cs
ps.AddArgument("Import-Module -Name Appx -UseWIndowsPowershell");
```

It didn't work.

Can someone help me figured it out?
Thanks.

Comment: Check which PowerShell version your application is using, the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` flag only exists in PowerShell Core (so starting with PS >= 6 IIRC)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @FlaubertTAGU. Note that `.AddScript()` is for adding _strings_ that contain PowerShell code. Use `.AddCommand()` for script _files_ and individual commands (arguments are added with `.AddParameter()` or `.AddArgument()`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51110482/45375).

Comment:  Maybe changing `ps.AddArgument("Import-Module -Name Appx -UseWIndowsPowershell");` to `ps.AddScript("Import-Module -Name Appx -UseWIndowsPowershell");` is enough - but note that each `.AddScript()` or `.AddCommand()` call must be followed by `.AddStatement()` if there are _multiple_ ones. If that doesn't help, you can inspect `ps.Streams.Error` for the errors that resulted, which will reveal the reason that importing failed.

Comment: Dear @mklement0 I found a simpler method. Instead of trying to install the .msix package from the powershell command, I just added a command to open the msix file right after the certificate has been installed correctly. Below the command

Comment: `var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(unpackDirectoryName)
{
 UseShellExecute = true
};
p.Start();`

Comment:  for posting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for community members who gave me advice.
I was at the same time trying to find another way.

The simplest solution I found was to open directly the .msix file from the app console command after the certificate has been installed in the "TrustedPeople" store in "local machine".

**the code to install the certificate correctly is the following:**

- `string certCommand0 = "Import-Certificate -FilePath 'THEFILEPATH' -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\\LocalMachine\\TrustedPeople' -Verbose";`
- `string certCommand1 = certCommand0.Replace("THEFILEPATH", certificate);`

**To open the .msix file package I used the following code:**

- `var p = new Process();`
- `p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath){ UseShellExecute = true };`
- `p.Start();`

Hope it will help someone.